# How to mock patch a django model field?

Tags: python, django, mocking

I have these 2 models:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    gateway_reference = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def abc(self):
        ...

class Item(models.Model):
    txn = models.ForeignKey('Transaction')

    def refund(self):
       Gateway.refund(self.txn)
```

In my unittest:

```
def test_decline(self):
    item = Item.objects.get(...)
    with patch('app.models.Transaction.gateway_reference', new='invalid reference'):
        item.refund()
```

But it complains that `Transaction class does not have the attribute 'gateway_reference'`

NOTE:
I am using similar patch for an property of a model class and it worked fine, eg.

```
with patch('app.models.Transaction.abc', new='lalala')
```

Answer (score -1):

When you instantiate the model with the line below

> > > item = Item.objects.get(...)

You have already created a reference to the Transaction model through the `txn` attribute. So patching the class `Transaction` within that namespace after the instantiation is too late.

I would use patch object here on the `item` instance. See https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object

Comment: that was my first attempt as well, but sadly it didn't change the value: `with patch.object(item.txn, 'gateway_reference', new='invalid gateway reference'):`